# What is artists in matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation?

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

So i am reading up on the documentation for `matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation` [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html), but i have a hard time understanding what artists is (are?). Does anyone have a clear and concise answer to this?

Comment: Where exactly is artist mentionned there? What would you like to understand about it`?

Comment: Basically a class that uses renderer to paint on a canvas. This might help: https://matplotlib.org/users/artists.html

Comment: The site helb commented did clarify a bit. As i understand it, a the `plt.plot(x, y) ` for example creates a Line2D object, which is one kind of artist object. Is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a rule of thumb you can say: Everything that you see on the canvas is an artist.

As [the artist tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/users/artists.html) puts it

> the `matplotlib.artist.Artist` is the object that knows how to use a renderer to paint onto the canvas. [...] the Artist handles all the high level constructs like representing and laying out the figure, text, and lines. The typical user will spend 95% of their time working with the Artists.
>
> There are two types of Artists: primitives and containers. The primitives represent the standard graphical objects we want to paint onto our canvas: Line2D, Rectangle, Text, AxesImage, etc., and the containers are places to put them (Axis, Axes and Figure). The standard use is to create a Figure instance, use the Figure to create one or more Axes or Subplot instances, and use the Axes instance helper methods to create the primitives.

Inverting that, one might say that you need to dig really deep to come across something that is not an artist. You may easily check if some object is an artist,

```
import matplotlib 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line,  = ax.plot([1,2,3])
scatter = ax.scatter([1,2,3],[2,3,1])

for some_object in [fig,ax,line,scatter]:
    print(isinstance(some_object, matplotlib.artist.Artist))
```

will all print `True`.

When it comes to animations, it is of course artists that you want to animate. The `FuncAnimation` itself is not an Artist (handwavingly, because you don't see it on the screen).

```
import matplotlib.animation
f =  lambda i: line.set_ydata(line.get_ydata()-0.02)
ani = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig, f, frames=20)

print(isinstance(ani, matplotlib.artist.Artist)) # prints False
```

But it needs a `Figure` as input as well as some function which will manipulate some artists properties (otherwise there would not be any animation seen). E.g. in the above, the y coordinates of the `line`'s data are changed in every iteration.